# Identifying core arguments, constituents?

Tags: syntax, semantics, phrase-structure, grammatical-subject, constituents

In the sentence, 'It was raining' what are the core arguments?
I think [It] is a core argument and [was raining] is another.  This would mean that *it* is a NP and *was raining* is a VP.  But if this is the case, then what type of argument (subject, direct object, indirect object, oblique) is *was raining* ? Would *raining* be a dependent of *was*?

Comment: You might want to say what theoretical framework you're assuming, because the answer depends on assumptions about e.g. what an "argument" or "core argument" is. It's unlikely that "was raining" would be any kind of argument, but maybe it is in some theory.

Comment: I don't know what "core argument" means.  "Was raining" is a predicate, not an argument.